# Get the div that's closest to the viewport's center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a lot of `div`s with the class `.story`, and I would like to asign the `.closest` class to the one that's closest to the center of the window and keep refreshing that function so there's only one with the `.closest` class but it's always the one closest to the center (Even when you scroll).

```css
body{  
  background-color:#ecf0f1;
}

.story
{
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
<div class="story">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a finite number of `class="story"` ?

Comment: Yes. But it loads more when it reaches the end.

Comment: Okay, so every time you scroll down, count the total number of stories you have, divide it by 2 to get the middle. Then apply the closest class using jQuery's nth-child(n).

Comment: That's not what I meant :c. It's more like the most visible of the `.story`s. The one that's closest to the center of the `viewport`, not the `document`

Comment: maybe you could find the middle of the viewport and then loop through the story elements and calculate the distance from the middle of the viewport to the middle point of each story